# Can I use "what are you talking about." with the words in that order?

Tags: grammar, word-order

We've got a dispute on the point whether the phrase should be "What you are talking about." or "What are you talking about." in the affirmative sentence.

I was arguing that it should be the former, and the word-order is not so important in that phrase, is it?

Help us solve the dispute, please :)

Answer (score 6):

In English, "What you are talking about" is not correct at all unless you were saying:

> "What you are talking about is....."

It would always be "What *are* you talking about?" in a question.

Comment: Thank you! But if it is an affirmative sentence should it be "What you are talking about." or "What are you talking about."?

Comment: Yes. One could say "What you are talking about is unrelated to physics".

Comment: You couldn't say "What are you talking about is..."

Comment: the phrase was "no idea what are you talking about." can it be said like that? thank you again!

Comment: No.  It's exactly the same but with two extra words.  Have you not settled this argument yet?  ;o)

Comment: not yet and it seems like I've lost the bet. Well, the more you know.. 
Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to accept my answer if it helped.  And I hope you come back to this site again soon.

Answer (score 3):

In English, an interrogative clause is marked by **subject-auxiliary inversion (SAI)**, a process in which a subject and auxiliary verb switch places.  Here, the auxiliary verb is *are*, and the subject is *you*:

1. Declarative clause (subject and auxiliary in basic position):

   > **You are** talking about *something*.
2. Interrogative clause (subject and auxiliary inverted):

   > **Are you** talking about *something*?

A typical question takes the form of an interrogative clause.  When it contains an interrogative phrase (containing or consisting of a *wh*-word such as *what*) that is not in subject position, that interrogative phrase is typically **fronted**, meaning it's moved to the front of the clause:

> 1. **You are** talking about *something*.
>    2. **You are** talking about *what*?
>    3. *what*<sub>*i*</sub> **you are** talking about ____<sub>*i*</sub>
>    4. *What*<sub>*i*</sub> **are you** talking about ____<sub>*i*</sub> ?

In 2, *what* is the object of the preposition *about*; when we move it to the front of the clause, it leaves behind a **gap** which cannot be filled.  In 3 and 4, the *wh*-word is understood as if it were the object of the preposition *about*, even though it doesn't actually occupy that position.  (I've marked both the gap and the *wh*-word with the index <sub>*i*</sub> to indicate that they refer to the same thing.)

In 3, we have a *wh*-relative clause.  It could be used as part of a larger sentence, but it's not a complete sentence itself, so I didn't capitalize it or put punctuation at the end.  In 4, because the subject and auxiliary have switched places, we have an interrogative clause--a complete sentence and a question.

Unlike an interrogative clause, a *wh*-relative clause cannot have the subject and auxiliary inverted:

> 5. (I have) no idea [ *what*<sub>*i*</sub> **you are** talking about ____<sub>*i*</sub> ]<sub>*wh*-relative</sub> .
>    6. *(I have) no idea [ *what*<sub>*i*</sub> **are you** talking about ____<sub>*i*</sub> ]<sub>*wh*-relative</sub> .

For this reason, example 5 is grammatical, while example 6 is not.  (I've placed the words *I have* in parentheses because they were omitted from your original sentence, but it makes no difference grammatically.)